# Django block content not working - Cant seem to make it work even after looking at some other solutions

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm doing some small course "Django for beginners", no point to say I'm like a super beginner.
I understand the concept of block content and templates. But for one bizarre reason, I can not make block content work and as such, I'm basically stuck. I looked through a lot of similar issues on this page but I guess I'm really missing something.

I have this really simple base html which is saved in a folder "templates"

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Base title</title>
    </head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    replace me
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

And I create a contact html also saved in my folder "templates"

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

In my settings I have defined the templates DIRS as such

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And my urls.py are set like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from Pages.views import home_view, contact_view, about_view, social_view


urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name = 'home'),
    path('contact/', contact_view),
    path('about/', about_view),
    path('social/', social_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I know that the contact pages does use the base.html pages because when I open the contact page in chrome the title of my header shows base title, but I should see "replace me" for the body content, but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content should be inside here

```py
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
replace me
{% endblock %}
```

and in the base.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Base title</title>
    </head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

also make sure that the contact.html is inside a folder named after your project inside templates

*templates/"folder with project name"/contact.html*

Comment: Many thanks to both of you. It seems I misunderstood it. It works now :)

Comment: @urbanespaceman I didn't see it when i posted, else i wouldn't have. I took time formatting the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have the "replace me" in the base template. It should be in the `contact.html`  file instead.

Basically, whatever is between the tags in the "parent" template gets replaced with what is between the tags in the child template. In your case, there is nothing between the tags in the child, so you see nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As per what you have written the output is correct.

From docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#block)

> Defines a block that can be overridden by child templates.

In your base html you have registered a template tag block named content with 'replace me' in it

```
{% block content %}
replace me
{% endblock %}
```

Extending the base html you have another file.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

In this file a template tag with the name content is registered inside that nothing is written.

Whenever there is a match with tag block names (here block tag named 'content') the content in the parent file(base.html) will be replaced with the content in the child file (contact.html).

here, parent file contains 'replace me' and child file contains ''. So, 'replace me' is replaced with ''.

If your contact me html is something like this

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
This is the contact page which shows contact info
{% endblock %}
```

The content in base file (replace me) will be replace with 'This is the contact page which shows contact info'